# Facebook Events of user with php sdk 5

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Any one have the experience to get events of user using Facebook SDK 5?

I am trying to get event like

```
$response = $fb->get('/me',$accessToken);
$userNode = $response->getGraphEvent();
```

No data is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/me` returns basic information of a User, it´s not related to events. In order to use `/me`, you need to authorize a User with Facebook Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

User events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/ (You would need the `user_events` permission for that)

Comment: thank you for your answer . It's help full . Can you please give me any  example to fetch user's events after getting user_events permission from user .

Comment: there is example code in the docs, just open the last link in my answer. just use the /me/events endpoint.

Comment: thank for your help , Can you please give me some more detail about 
"user_events needs to get approved by Facebook before it works with any user, else it will only work for users with a role in your app"
I read your comment form another question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105247/cannot-get-permission-for-user-events-facebook"

Comment: how  any permission I can get approved by Facebook ?

Comment: that is explained very well in the docs, it´s called "login review": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review